# Express + Passport: req.user resets on every code save

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

Whenever I save a new code, my `req.user` is reset in my Express app.

I am using Twitter strategy, and here is how I mounted my passport middlewares:

```
app.use(cookieParser('secret'));
app.use(session({
  secret: 'secret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Here is serialize and deserialize logic:

```
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

Any idea why this is happening? And how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, you did something in your app code, and then you notice that you lost session?
Default session storage is memory. When you did something in code, you must restart application (or you use other app to do that(nodemon,forever etc)). And when you restart app, then app memory is clean. Therefore your session is lost.
You can store session in file or db: 
example with redis db (code from documentation):
install https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-redis
then in app:

```
var session = require('express-session');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

app.use(session({
    store: new RedisStore(options),
    secret: 'keyboard cat'
}));
```

Comment: Yes I was using nodemon and it was restarting the app whenever a file changed. Is using Redis a common solution while developing app with passportjs?

Comment: your problem is related specifically to standard session plugin (passport is using it to make persistent authentication. If you not disable session in authentication then after authentication each request there is call to session to check if user is valid). 
Yes redis is very popular for this type of problems, (also mongodb )